# Reg syncfusion grid dispose memory consumption issue

Tags: c#, memory, grid, syncfusion

I am writing a Windows application.

In `onLoad` of the form I have created a grid which has 10000 rows and also added a button below the grid.

In `onClick` of the button I added functionality to dispose of the grid.

Everything is working fine but I am facing the memory problems, i.e. before disposing of the grid memory consumption is `70664k` but after disposing the grid memory consumption is `70820k`.

To dispose of the grid I'm using just `Gridctrl.Dispose();` and also called `Gc.collect()` but didn't find any difference.

How should I properly dispose of the grid to free the memory?

Answer (score 0):

Grid Control can be disposed by using "Dispose()" method. The Latest version of syncfusion will dispose the grid controls without any memory leak.

Kindly, check disposing the object with latest version.

Comment: Do you have any reliable sources to back this statement? It's an incredibly interesting one, since we are experiencing memory leaks with a version from last year (2013)...